# CREATE MULTIPLE SCHEMA using a name stored

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create new schema on my postgres database which names are stored on an existing table,
my query look like this:

```
DO $$
    declare s_name text;
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT schema_name
          FROM information_schema.schemata
          
    THEN
        SELECT name INTO s_name FROM table_name;
        execute 'create schema '|| quote_ident(s_name);
    Raise notice 'status:%', schema created successfully;
    END IF;

END
$$;
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: there are multiple values stored in existing table so need to create multiple schemas dynamically and which should not exist, tried to loop it but got stucked between

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems: first the `if not exists` will never be true because the select will always return at least one row as there are at least three schemas in every Postgres database. You don't really need that check to begin with, as you can use `create schema if not exists`

The second problem is, that you are not looping over the result, you are just picking one row of that table.

```
DO $$
declare 
  l_rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR l_rec IN select name from table_name
    LOOP 
      execute format('create schema if not exists %I', l_rec.name);
    END loop;
END
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and Yes it's working. Here i have a doubt. is it possible to concatenate string and schema name while creating. EX: name is - "Test" and i want to create schema like "Test_First" (execute format('create schema if not exists %I', l_rec.name'||'_first);).